# Best way to aggregate total size of objects in nested GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have several PiB of data nested under a bucket and they’re categorized as:

Bucket/UNIQUE_ID/[A,B,C,D]

Now I’m curious on how I can run a query to understand total bytes stored (for example):

Bucket/UNIQUE_ID/A

For each unique ID I have stored in the bucket.

What’s the most cost effective way of running this analysis?

Comment: What do you mean by analysis? I would list the contents of the entire bucket and import the details into BigQuery. Then I could use SQL to query details.

Comment: Thanks, I’m used to AWS, so I’m unfamiliar with the tooling, but it gives me a good starting point. It looks like movement between GCS and Big Query is free. Can I import only object metadata like parent dir and file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the bucket size programatically like:

```python
import sys

from google.cloud import storage

bucket_name = 'qpalzm-bucket'
client = storage.Client()
bytes_used = sum(
    [blob.size for blob in client.list_blobs(bucket_name, delimiter='/')]
)

print(
    f"{bucket_name} is using {bytes_used/1048576:0.6f} MiB."
)

iterator = client.list_blobs(bucket_name, delimiter='/')
response = iterator._get_next_page_response()

for prefix in response['prefixes']:
    iterator2 = client.list_blobs(bucket_name,  prefix=prefix, delimiter='/')
    response2 = iterator2._get_next_page_response()
    if ('prefixes' in response2):
        for prefix2 in response2['prefixes']:
            bytes_used = sum(
                [blob.size for blob in client.list_blobs(bucket_name,  prefix=prefix2, delimiter='/')]
            )

            print(
                f"{bucket_name}/{prefix2} is using {bytes_used/1048576:0.6f} MiB."
            )


    bytes_used = sum(
        [blob.size for blob in client.list_blobs(bucket_name,  prefix=prefix, delimiter='/')]
    )

    print(
        f"{bucket_name}/{prefix} is using {bytes_used/1048576:0.6f} MiB."
    )
```

Sample output:

[image]

You could also utilize the Metrics Explorer under Cloud Monitoring, on Metrics Explorer > Filter Resource & Metric by `GCS Bucket Total Bytes` to show usage for all buckets in your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsutil du, which is the tool you might use for this analysis. There is no faster way to do it.

But if you need to do it regularly, you may need to enable bucket logging:

You can read more about it, here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#delivery

Although about the cost, It counts as a class B operation

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Comment: Are you sure it's not a class A operation?

Comment: Since you are retrieving metadata in 1 call should be 1 B operation